# How to prevent PatchUpdateException on json deserialization?

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson

I'm parsing json with custom desereailizer. It reads JsonNode and then deserializes entity from json by ObjectMapper.

```
public static class CustomDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<Custom> implements ResolvableDeserializer {
    private final JsonDeserializer<?> defaultDeserializer;
    public CustomDeserializer(JsonDeserializer<?> defaultDeserializer) {
        super(Custom.class);
        this.defaultDeserializer = defaultDeserializer;
    }

    @Override
    public Custom deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        final ObjectNode node = jp.readValueAsTree();
        // some node structure validation
        try (final TreeTraversingParser newJsonParser = new TreeTraversingParser(node)) {
            newJsonParser.nextToken();
            return (Custom) defaultDeserializer.deserialize(newJsonParser, ctxt);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void resolve(DeserializationContext ctxt) throws JsonMappingException {
        ((ResolvableDeserializer) defaultDeserializer).resolve(ctxt);
    }
}
```

On some requests it works, on other throws

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser cannot be cast to com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.TreeTraversingParser
```

or

```
m.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser cannot be cast to com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.TreeTraversingParser
```

How to prevent that case?